# firebase database ref update method is not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

To update the keys and values in my firebase data from javascript , When I do this : -

`ref.update({"key" : "value" }) ;`

It works fine and updates the data in my firebase database .

---

But when I do this :-

```
    data = {} ;
    email = "mymail"
    pass="pass"
    data[email] = pass
    ref.update(data);
```

Does't work and when I see the database nothing would have been updated. How to fix this ?

**EDIT 1:-**

If I directly give , `ref.update({email , pass})` , what happens is it updates the data in the database but instead of the string in the email it just stores 'email' as the key in the database . Any fix ?

Comment: You have an error trace?, what is the key/value you expected, this?: "mymail@server.com": "my password"  ?

Comment: Are you sure about the first block? I think should work: "ref.update({'key': 'value'});

Comment: i mistyped while asking question . That doesn't fix it . save error

Comment: About your edit 1 above, and with the example I referred to below, just execute the following on your console and you will see the reason var updates = {};
updates['/posts/'] = 'a';
updates['/user-posts/'] = 'b';  console.log(updates);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you don't miss the / separators?? see the following example from https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

```
var updates = {};
updates['/posts/' + newPostKey] = postData;
updates['/user-posts/' + uid + '/' + newPostKey] = postData;

return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
```

Comment: Im sure its not what ur suggesting